# Why does BEM often use two underscores instead of one for modifiers?

Tags: css, bem

In BEM, I understand that with modifiers, two dashes makes sense so that you can distinguish the modifier in `my-block-my-modifier` with `my-block--my-modifier`.

But **why use `block__element` instead of `block_element`?**

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Double Underscore is used to define sub element of a block.

i.e:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <a class="main-nav__item" href="#">Text</a>
</nav>
```

Where `main-nav` is a block & `main-nav__item` is a sub element.

This is done because some people might name their block like this `main_nav` which will create confusion with single underscore like this : `main_nav_item`

Therefore double underscore will clarify stuff like this: `main_nav__item`.

Comment: In the Developer Tools, dashes and underscores both easily cause confusion. Classnames in camel case are clearer.

Answer (score 13):

I'm going to 2nd @Imran Bughio's answer, but I'm trying to further clarify the issue.

In [*standard* BEM style](http://bem.info/method/definitions/), single underscores are reserved for *modifiers*. Also, they usually represent a combination of key/value pairs. E.g.

```
.block_align_vertical
.block_align_horizontal
.block__element_size_big
.block__element_size_small
```

This is in contrast to the *modified* BEM syntax championed by [inuit.css](https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css) for example, which are boolean.

```
.block--vertical
.block--horizontal
.block__element--big
.block__element--small
```

From my experience when using the modified syntax, you quickly run into expression limitations. E.g. if you would write

```
.block--align-vertical
.block--align-horizontal
.block__element--size-big
.block__element--size-small
```

The key/value relation would not be unique, if you would try to describe a key such as `background-attachment` which would result in

```
.block__element--background-attachment-fixed
```

Another added benefit is, that you can use the libraries based on the *standard* naming convention for added productivity in your workflow:

- http://bem.info/tools/bem/bem-tools/
- https://github.com/hoho/jquery-bem

Comment: I don't see the problem with using double dash for modifiers... it's visually different enough to underscore that it makes makes class names with modifiers look different enough. If we're talking about how complex something looks... `.block__element_background-attachment-fixed` isn't really much different from using double-dash though is it, except that now, at first glance your class looks like a `block__element` not a `block__element--modifier`? scanability in a codebase is all about shapes

Answer (score 7):

It's also worth mentioning that the BEM syntax is not forced upon us and if you find another syntax that you find more readable then by all means go with that.  The important thing is consistency, ensuring other developers work to the same syntax.

An example of an alternative syntax used is in [SUIT CSS](http://suitcss.github.io/) by Nicolas Gallagher.  Which uses the following syntax.

```
ComponentName
ComponentName--modifierName
ComponentName-elementName
ComponentName.is-stateOfComponent
```

You can read more here [SUIT CSS naming conventions](https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/naming-conventions.md)

Comment: Thanks Colin, I really like SUIT CSS naming as well and **[plan on using it in the near future](https://github.com/gilbox/futuristic-sass-guide)**

Answer (score 4):

Because whose blocks can be hyphen or underscore delimited, for example:

```
.site-search {} /* Block */
.site-search__field {} /* Element */
.site-search--full {} /* Modifier */
```

or

```
.site_search {} /* Block */
.site_search__field {} /* Element */
.site_search--full {} /* Modifier */
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [BEM naming convention](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#naming-rules), single underscore has two other usages,

> 1. The modifier name is separated from the block or element name by a single underscore (_).
> 2. The modifier value is separated from the modifier name by a single underscore (_).

So for separating element name from the block name is done by a double underscore.

> The element name is separated from the block name by a double underscore (__).

Answer (score 0):

**The basic concept:** block-name__element-name_modifier-name

**Further details:** [BEM (Block, Element, Modifier)](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/)