# Is this more than one class?

Tags: css

So I've got this code I worked through a tutorial with.

It is: `<div>Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle</div>`

My question is what the unscores represent? A break into a second classes. 
It's just a weird naming convention and feels very alien.

Comment: I formatted your code, which had hidden '<div>'s in it. Can you verify that this is correct before people start answering?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but underscore is not presenting anything. In the best case is more like convention, not a rule. Css "doesn't care" if it underscore or the letter `a` or any other allowed characters.

Comment: BEM: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/organizing-css-oocss-smacss-and-bem/

Answer (score 1):

The double underscores are a naming convention used in "[Block Element Modifier](http://getbem.com/)" style CSS, used to define the sub-element of a block.

So, Link is a sub-element of Nav, etc.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24670392/244811) :

> this is done because some people might name their block like this
>   main_nav which will create confusion with single underscore like this
>   : main_nav_item

Comment: Scott Thanks for putting this straight. never heard of BEM. <div>Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle</div> I'd been trying rework them as classes like so : navbarLink, navbarLinkToggle. Would this be right. I'm just getting my head around this.

Comment: I actually don't use BEM either, and that's fine and a matter of taste - especially if you aren't dealing with a particularly complex DOM